# How to return default semantics from System.Speech.Recognition when "optional" items are omitted?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, speech

I am an intermediate C# programmer but an absolute beginner with System.Speech.  I am working through some examples to get the feel of how the API works, and I'm already hung up on the first example...  What I am trying to do is have a grammar which returns default semantics for one or more expected choices if the user does not explicitly provide a value for one of those choices. (Sorry if my terminology's not quite right...)  I am on Windows Vista with Visual Studio 2010 (trial version), and .NET 4.0 installed.

I started from the "pizza ordering" example in the following article, which seems to come up on the forums quite a bit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx#S5

The code I started with is in Figure 9 of that article.  Unfortunately, for some reason (possibly changes from one version of SAPI to the next?), a number of the function calls are not actually valid in .NET 4.0/SAPI 5.3, for example GrammarBuilder.AppendChoices() and GrammarBuilder.AppendResultKeyValue().  The latter call is what is supposed to give us default choices for the "size" and "crust" keys if the user only specifies toppings (i.e. "A cheese pizza, please" hands back size=large, crust=thick, and topping=cheese)... so I am trying to figure out how to make this work.

Here's the relevant section of my code (which is supposed to be just a rewrite of the code in the above article):

```
// [I'd like] a [< size >] [< crust >] [< topping >] pizza [please]

// build the core set of choices  
GrammarBuilder grbSizes = new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("small", "regular", "large"));  
GrammarBuilder grbCrusts = new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("thin crust", "thick crust"));  
GrammarBuilder grbToppings = new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("vegetarian", "pepperoni", "cheese"));    

// Wrap them in semantic result keys
SemanticResultKey skeySize = new SemanticResultKey("size", grbSizes);  
SemanticResultKey skeyCrust = new SemanticResultKey("crust", grbCrusts);  
SemanticResultKey skeyTopping = new SemanticResultKey("topping", grbToppings);  

// And some default values for later on...    
SemanticResultKey skeyDefaultSize = new SemanticResultKey("size", new GrammarBuilder(new SemanticResultValue("large")));  
SemanticResultKey skeyDefaultCrust = new SemanticResultKey("crust", new GrammarBuilder(new SemanticResultValue("thick crust")));  


// [...snip...]  
// Here's the builder for one of several sub-grammars, the one with two default  
// values... This should allow "cheese" in "A cheese pizza" to be intepreted  
// as large+thick-crust+cheese

//choose topping only, and assume the rest
GrammarBuilder toppingOnly = new GrammarBuilder();
toppingOnly += skeyTopping;
toppingOnly += skeyDefaultSize;
toppingOnly += skeyDefaultCrust;

// [...snip...]
// Later code builds up the full pattern just as in the original article
```

I am aware that [the MSDN page for the SemanticResultKey constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd167587(v=office.13).aspx) includes a warning that "There should be one, and only one, untagged SemanticResultValue instance in the GrammarBuilder objects specified by the *builders* parameter", or else you'll get an exception. And indeed, I do get a TargetInvocationException here when I say something like "A cheese pizza" into the recognizer.

So my first question is, can someone explain to me what is going on here? I wouldn't necessarily have expected this constraint to apply here, since (a) I thought that my declarations for skeyDefaultSize and skeyDefaultCrust were indeed associating the SemanticResultValues with SemanticResultKeys, so these Values should not be considered as "untagged"; and (b) the two SemanticResultValues in question are actually from different GrammarBuilders which are in turn inside of different SemanticResultKeys, which doesn't seem to be the scenario described on the MSDN page.

Then my second question is, why DOES the following code work?  The only difference is that I have re-ordered some lines so that the two "default" keys are not appended to the grammar consecutively.

```
//choose topping only, and assume the rest
GrammarBuilder toppingOnly = new GrammarBuilder();
toppingOnly += skeyDefaultSize;
toppingOnly += skeyTopping;
toppingOnly += skeyDefaultCrust;
```

This gives the exact desired result when I say e.g. "A cheese pizza"-- all the keys ("size", "crust", "topping") are present in the SemanticValue that I catch in my SpeechRecognized handler, with the desired default values for size and crust plus the user-specified value for the topping.

I guess the third and most important question is: Is there some way to do this properly? Obviously, tweaking the order of the appends is too "magical" and will not always be a viable solution.

Sorry for the huge question, and thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem learning from the MSDN article. I don't know that my solution is "the best", but this is how I updated the Pizza grammar and handled the default selections.

First, this is how I create the pizza grammar:

```
private Grammar CreatePizzaGrammar()
{
    //create the pizza grammar
    GrammarBuilder pizzaRequest = CreatePizzaGrammarBuilder();
    Grammar pizzaGrammar = new Grammar(pizzaRequest);
    return pizzaGrammar;
}

private GrammarBuilder CreatePizzaGrammarBuilder()
{
    // this is adapted from the sample in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx
    // but the API changed before Vista was released so some changes were made.

    //[I'd like] a [<size>] [<crust>] [<topping>] pizza [please]

    //build the core set of choices

    // size
    Choices sizes = new Choices();
    SemanticResultValue sizeSRV;
    sizeSRV = new SemanticResultValue("small", "small");
    sizes.Add(sizeSRV);
    sizeSRV = new SemanticResultValue("regular", "regular");
    sizes.Add(sizeSRV);
    sizeSRV = new SemanticResultValue("medium", "regular");
    sizes.Add(sizeSRV);
    sizeSRV = new SemanticResultValue("large", "large");
    sizes.Add(sizeSRV);
    SemanticResultKey sizeSemKey = new SemanticResultKey("size", sizes);

    // crust
    Choices crusts = new Choices();
    SemanticResultValue crustSRV;
    crustSRV = new SemanticResultValue("thin crust", "thin crust");
    crusts.Add(crustSRV);
    crustSRV = new SemanticResultValue("thin", "thin crust");
    crusts.Add(crustSRV);
    crustSRV = new SemanticResultValue("thick crust", "thick crust");
    crusts.Add(crustSRV);
    crustSRV = new SemanticResultValue("thick", "thick crust");
    crusts.Add(crustSRV);
    SemanticResultKey crustSemKey = new SemanticResultKey("crust", crusts);

    // toppings
    Choices toppings = new Choices();
    SemanticResultValue toppingSRV;
    toppingSRV = new SemanticResultValue("vegetarian", "vegetarian");
    toppings.Add(toppingSRV);
    toppingSRV = new SemanticResultValue("veggie", "vegetarian");
    toppings.Add(toppingSRV);
    toppingSRV = new SemanticResultValue("pepperoni", "pepperoni");
    toppings.Add(toppingSRV);
    toppingSRV = new SemanticResultValue("cheese", "cheese");
    toppings.Add(toppingSRV);
    toppingSRV = new SemanticResultValue("plain", "cheese");
    toppings.Add(toppingSRV);
    SemanticResultKey toppingSemKey = new SemanticResultKey("topping", toppings);

    //build the permutations of choices...

    // 1. choose all three
    GrammarBuilder sizeCrustTopping = new GrammarBuilder();
    sizeCrustTopping.Append(sizeSemKey);
    sizeCrustTopping.Append(crustSemKey);
    sizeCrustTopping.Append(toppingSemKey);

    // 2. choose size and topping
    GrammarBuilder sizeAndTopping = new GrammarBuilder();
    sizeAndTopping.Append(sizeSemKey);
    sizeAndTopping.Append(toppingSemKey);
    // sizeAndTopping.Append(new SemanticResultKey("crust", "thick crust"));
    // sizeAndTopping.AppendResultKeyValue("crust", "thick crust");

    // 3. choose size and crust, and assume cheese
    GrammarBuilder sizeAndCrust = new GrammarBuilder();
    sizeAndCrust.Append(sizeSemKey);
    sizeAndCrust.Append(crustSemKey);

    // 4. choose topping and crust, and assume cheese
    GrammarBuilder toppingAndCrust = new GrammarBuilder();
    toppingAndCrust.Append(crustSemKey);
    toppingAndCrust.Append(toppingSemKey);


    // 5. choose topping only, and assume the rest
    GrammarBuilder toppingOnly = new GrammarBuilder();
    toppingOnly.Append(toppingSemKey);         //, "topping");

    // 6. choose size only, and assume the rest
    GrammarBuilder sizeOnly = new GrammarBuilder();
    sizeOnly.Append(sizeSemKey);

    // 7. choose crust only, and assume the rest
    GrammarBuilder crustOnly = new GrammarBuilder();
    crustOnly.Append(crustSemKey);


    //assemble the permutations             
    Choices permutations = new Choices();
    permutations.Add(sizeCrustTopping);
    permutations.Add(sizeAndTopping);
    permutations.Add(sizeAndCrust);
    permutations.Add(toppingAndCrust);
    permutations.Add(toppingOnly);
    permutations.Add(sizeOnly);
    permutations.Add(crustOnly);

    GrammarBuilder permutationList = new GrammarBuilder();
    permutationList.Append(permutations);

    //now build the complete pattern...
    GrammarBuilder pizzaRequest = new GrammarBuilder();
    //pre-amble "[I'd like] a"
    pizzaRequest.Append(new Choices("I'd like a", "a", "I need a", "I want a"));
    //permutations "[<size>] [<crust>] [<topping>]"
    pizzaRequest.Append(permutationList, 0, 1);
    //post-amble "pizza [please]"
    pizzaRequest.Append(new Choices("pizza", "pizza please", "pie", "pizza pie"));

    return pizzaRequest;
}
```

Then I set up an event handler for the SpeechRecognized event as:

```
void recognizer_SpeechRecognizedPizza(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{

    // set the default semantic key values if the result does not include these
    string size = "regular";
    string crust = "thick crust";
    string topping = "cheese";

    if (e.Result.Semantics != null && e.Result.Semantics.Count != 0)
    {
        if (e.Result.Semantics.ContainsKey("size"))
        {
            size = e.Result.Semantics["size"].Value.ToString();
            AppendTextOuput(String.Format("\r\n  Size = {0}.", size));
        }

        if (e.Result.Semantics.ContainsKey("crust"))
        {
            crust = e.Result.Semantics["crust"].Value.ToString();
            AppendTextOuput(String.Format("\r\n  Crust = {0}.", crust));
        }

        if (e.Result.Semantics.ContainsKey("topping"))
        {
            topping = e.Result.Semantics["topping"].Value.ToString();
            AppendTextOuput(String.Format("\r\n  Topping = {0}.", topping));
        }
    }
    String sOutput = String.Format("\r\nRecognized: You have orderd a {0}, {1}, {2} pizza.", size, crust, topping);
    AppendTextOuput(sOutput);
}
```

AppendTextOuput is just my own little output string method.

This seemed like a lot of work to explicitly layout all the possible permutations in the grammar. But, it works really well.

As you can see, I ended up avoiding the issue of having the grammar provide the default and simply built it into the event handler. There is probably a better way.

One other step to learn more is to use the SrgsDocument.WriteSrgs() [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.srgsgrammar.srgsdocument.writesrgs%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and write out an SRGS XML document that represents the grammar. The rule and semantic tags are much easier to visualize in XML.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  That does look like a lot of work :) but it gives me some more insight on how semantic keys and values work (e.g. the trick of having both "regular" and "medium" evaluate to the value "regular"). I guess if I were building a real app with a more complicated grammar, I would probably refactor some of those long lists of .Add and .Append calls into a helper function or something.  I'd still like to know if there is a way to put more than one default value INSIDE the grammar, even though putting the defaults in the event handler seems like a decent workaround...

Comment: I'm not an expert here. I hit the same wall as you reading that MSDN article and this is how I got the sample to work. I read the docs to mean that SemanticResultValue lets you map multiple words or phrases to the same semantic meaning (the value) and the SemanticResultKey is the placeholder for the choices represented by those values. This is probably an oversimplified view of these APIs, but it is certainly one of the usage scenarios they support. I'm sure there are more advanced ways to use these APIs as well.